# blank option in select fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to fill my option fields by data from database.
I am getting error in console:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!
```

I know that Json send my data properly cause I see output when I did smth like that: myaddress.com/forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info

**Output:**

> [{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Julia"}]

**Angular Function:**

```
$scope.ChooseLogins = [];
$scope.getLogins = function () {
    $http.get('forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info').then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.chooseLogins = data;
        console.log('Retrieved data from server');
        console.log(data);
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
        console.log(data, status);
    });
};
$scope.getLogins();
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-select ng-model="getLogins" ng-options="logins.id for logins in chooseLogins">
    <md-option value="{{logins.id}}">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1837). unfortunately you cannot use `ng-options` on any other element except `<select>` which `<md-select>` isn't even if it looks like it is.

Comment: in addition to George's comment, take a look at [mdSelect Usage](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment, you cannot use `ng-options` on any other element except `<select>` which `<md-select>` isn't, what's recommended and in the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#usage) is to use an `ng-repeat` on the `<md-options>`. Example

```
<md-select ng-model="login">
    <md-option ng-repeat="logins in chooseLogins" ng-value="logins.id">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

To make it so that you don't have an empty option, you need to set the model to equal the first id in the array. Also note you have your model the same name as your function, you'll need to change this.

**[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhj0w32b/1/)** to show you how to do it.

For your code change it to this

```
$scope.getLogins = function () {
    $http.get('forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info').then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.chooseLogins = response.data;
        $scope.login = $scope.chooseLogins[0].id;
        console.log('Retrieved data from server');
        console.log(data);
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
        console.log(data, status);
    });
};
```

As an extra you may want to check the length of the data returned before setting it.

Comment: I did like that but I still have empty fields hmm.

Comment: Hmm I get proper rows in select options ( 2 rows cause I have 2 record in table ) but still is blink.

Comment: Error: $scope.chooseLogins[0] is undefined

Comment: $scope.chooseLogins = data.data; Use this instead $scope.chooseLogins = data;

Comment: @AnkitVadi Thanks, will edit the answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ng-repeat.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.css" />
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function () {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($interval, $mdDialog) {
      var vm = this;        
vm.chooseLogins = [{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Julia"}];
    });

})();
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" 
        ng-app="MyApp"
        >
      
     
     <p>{{ctrl.chooseLogins}}</p><br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Choose name...</label>
      <md-select ng-model="getLogins">
    <md-option ng-repeat="logins in ctrl.chooseLogins" ng-value="logins.id">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>
<p>{{getLogins}}</p>
    </div>
    
    
  </body>
  

</html>
```